# split textarea value properly jQuery regex

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having problems to properly split textarea value. My current snippet split each line that starts with "-" and displays it as value of span element, but, it wont collect next line value which does not start with "-".

For example if I paste this text into textarea:

```
- first match 
rest of first match
- second match
- third match
```

Script should output:

```
<span style="color:red;">- first match rest of first match </span><br>
<span style="color:red;">- second match</span><br>
<span style="color:red;">- third match</span><br>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const regex = /^\s*-\s*/;
  $("#txt").keyup(function() {
    const entered = $('#textarea').val()
    const lines = entered.split(/\n/);

    let spans = "";
    for (const line of lines) {
      if (regex.test(line)) {
        spans += "<span style='color:red;'>- " + line.replace(regex, '') + "</span><br/>";
      }
    }

    $(".results").html(spans);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <form>
        <textarea id="textarea" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 results"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, basically script should split textarea value from line that starts with "-" until next line which starts "-".

Code snippet is also available here: https://jsfiddle.net/zecaffe/f7zv3udh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just a split to the `\n-`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#textarea").keyup(function() {

    const entered = $('#textarea').val()
    const lines = entered.split(/\n-/);
    
    let spans = "";
    lines.forEach((l,i)=>{
      // remove the first -
      if(i===0 && l[0]==="-") l = l.slice(1)
      spans += "<span style='color:red;'>- " + l + "</span><br/>";
    })

    $(".results").html(spans);
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <form>
        <textarea id="textarea" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="Type something here..."></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 results"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! I had idea to use "\n-" but every time i try it i make a syntax error or an if logic error... thank you for your time and help! Best regards.